How to pack movie files in blender?
I'm using a movie file as a texture for a plane in my scene. I need to pack it somehow so I can get it rendered on sheepit. I managed to do this before but cant quite remember how I did it?
Any tips?

I don't think you can pack movies within the file, you can only pack images or sounds

Basically, I have a movie file as an image texture on a plane. I want to upload it on Sheept. This is why I asked how to pack it. Since I cant pack a movie file do you have another solution for this?

can't you send a folder with both the file and the movie?

Go to the file menu and the options are all there


Basically, I have a movie file as an image texture on a plane. I want to upload it on Sheept. This is why I asked how to pack it. Now apparently you cant pack a movie file do you have another solution for this?

@Tom, I would try to convert the video into still images (You can probably do that in a separate blender file, add the video in the sequencer and render animation with output as png/tif). Then you use the "image sequence" option in your texture. Hopefully you can pack the images that way, but I'm not entirely sure, maybe you need to pack frame by frame, this should be experimented.

You can't pack movies within the file, you can only pack images or sounds. If you need to render with a render farm, check on their website how it is supposed to work.
